# What decides that a anime series gets a sequel or not?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history

A lot of the anime I've watched are single, double or triple season anime series like Durarara!, Code Geass, Hagure Yuusha no Aesthetica, and Nabari no Ou, just to name a few. But there are also shows like Bleach, Naruto, D Grey Man, and Katekyo Hitman Reborn that have 300 or more episodes.

Why is that? How is it decided that these series get to go on so long?

Comment: Money. Pretty much just money. Sometimes it's because there's more source material to adapt, but that only matters if adapting it will make money.

Comment: Sometimes a long-running, popular manga will be produced with the foreknowledge that the anime will be produced almost continuously.  That is why we do not  generally think of "seasons" for *One Piece*, *Naruto*, *Fairy Tale*, etc. As @Torisuda said this decision still boils down to money.  Sometimes expectations are not met, or other factors interfere, and a long-running series will suddenly just end, even with significant manga content left.  This happened with *World Trigger*. Its network just decided to show sports rather than anime.